# Using NSOperationQueue as a view controller instance variable

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

If I have a view controller that has an `NSOperationQueue` as an instance variable, then what happens to any operations that are executing in the queue if the view controller gets unloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid mistake in my original answer. I've read this exact documentation wrong before. The real answer is that **it isn't defined what happens** or at least **it's not documented**.

As I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9208543/608157) there are a few things that suggest that the operation queue will be retained (like the fact that GCD-queues are retained while executing blocks).

[This question about autoreleasing an NSOperationQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2500933/608157) also says the same thing:

> There's nothing in the documentation to say what happens when the NSOperationQueue is released.

*You could of course interpret "the specified operation remains in the queue until it finishes executing" as the queue won't go away until the enqueued operation has finished executing but I still wouldn't count on it.*

You can however cancel the operations if you want to be sure that they doesn't execute by tell the operation queue to `cancelAllOperations` when your view controller gets unloaded if you want to prevent this. Note that the operations doesn't stop by them selves. They need to check `if ([self isCancelled]) { ... }` and stop there.

---

#### Original answer:

<s>All operations will finish executing since they retain their queue. From [the documentation of `addOperation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperation:)</s>

> **Discussion**
>
> Once added, the specified operation remains in the queue until it finishes executing.